# List pages and display subtitle

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been trying to display the subtitle for each children page of the current parent page. At the moment i've got it working so that it shows all the title's of the children pages.

Basically I want it to show the subtitle underneath each title of the children pages.

```
// Get childern
$children = ($post->post_parent) ? wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->post_parent.'&echo=0') :  wp_list_pages('title_li=&child_of='.$post->ID.'&echo=0');

// Set subtitle      
$subtitle = get_the_title($post->the_subtitle);

echo $children;
echo $subtitle;
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: how did you get subtitle support? did you install a plugin or are you using a custom field?

Comment: I had a plugin called WP Subtitle installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options for this:

### 1. The OOP approach

Extend the `Walker_page` class to create a custom iterator to use with `wp_list_pages()`.

Add this to your `functions.php`:

```
class Subtitle_walker extends Walker_page {
        function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page) {
        if ( $depth )
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);
        if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
            $_current_page = get_page( $current_page );
            _get_post_ancestors($_current_page);
            if ( isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors) )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
            if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
            elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        }

        $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

        //Added subtitle support
        $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(72,72)) .'</a>'.' <span class="subtitle">'.get_the_subtitle($page->ID,'','',0).'</span>';

        if ( !empty($show_date) ) {
            if ( 'modified' == $show_date )
                $time = $page->post_modified;
            else
                $time = $page->post_date;

            $output .= " " . mysql2date($date_format, $time);
        }
    }
}
```

And call it in your template file:

```
$subtitle_menu = new Subtitle_walker();
$args = array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'child_of' => ($post->post_parent) ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID,
    'echo'  => 0,
    'walker' => $subtitle_menu
);
$children =  wp_list_pages($args);
echo $children;
```

**Note:** the previous code is based on [this tutorial](http://badfunproductions.com/create-a-custom-walker-class-to-extend-wp_list_pages/), you can read it to get an in-depth explanation of what it's doing

### 2. Using custom WP_Query loop

You can use [`get_page_children`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_children) to query the child pages and then loop through them and build/echo your custom list items:

```
//Set up the objects needed
$my_wp_query = new WP_Query();
$all_wp_pages = $my_wp_query->query(array('post_type' => 'page'));

//Get children
$children = ($post->post_parent) ? get_page_children( $post->post_parent, $all_wp_pages ) :  get_page_children( $post->ID, $all_wp_pages );

//Build custom items 
foreach($children as $child){
    echo '<li class="page-item">';
    echo '<a href="'.get_permalink($child->ID).'">'.get_the_title($child->ID).'</a><br/>';
    echo '<span class="subtitle">'.get_the_subtitle($child->ID).'</span>';
    echo '</li>';
}
```

Comment: Hi koala_dev, 

Thanks so much for your response. Option 2, Using custom WP_Query loop, was what I was looking for. Thanks so much. 

Cheers
Tim